# How to convert nvarchar datatype to numeric

Tags: sql, t-sql, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I need to convert an nvarchar datatype to numeric since it's giving me an error when I tried to convert it this way.

```
   cast(memberid as numeric(10,0) as memberid
```

would this work the same way?

```
   case when ISNUMERIC(memberid) = 1 then cast(memberid as numeric(10,0)) else NULL end As memberid
```

any help would be appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Sql Server 2012+ use: `try_convert(numeric(10,0),memberid)`

---

In Sql Server 2012 and up: each of these will return `null` when the conversion fails instead of an error.

- [**`try_convert(datatype,val)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx)
- [**`try_cast(val as datatype)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx)
- [**`try_parse(val as datatype [using culture])`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx)
- [Why doesn’t `isnumeric()` work correctly? (SQL Spackle)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/)